# search mysql database using more keywords using php

Tags: php, mysql, search

Based on caste,religion,location,gender,age i need to filter data from my database,how shall i do it.

In mysql database i have religion,gender,,location,age as separate column in same table.

Code i have used

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM enquiry where location like '%$text%'and gender like'%$text1%' ")
                                                          or        die("error"); 
$found=mysql_num_rows($result); 

if($found>0){ 
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
 //display of data 
  }
```

Using this i can search data from one column using one keyword...as i am new please give me right way to slove this using php .

Comment: How about `or someothercolumn like '%$text%'`?

Comment: i don't understand your question...

Comment: or... `location REGEXP "text1|text2|text3"` or  `location in ('text1','text2','text3')`

Comment: I am getting data from user form as text. i have to select data from database whose location is text and gender is text1 and so on...@ gloomy.penguin

Answer (score 0):

Use the OR operator

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM enquiry where location like '%$text%' OR caste like '%$text%' OR religion like '%$text%' OR gender like '%$text%' OR age like '%$text%'")
                                                          or        die("error"); 
$found=mysql_num_rows($result); 

if($found>0){ 
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
 //display of data 
  }
```

Comment: I need to search not same text in all those field ...i have to match text with location ,text1 with gender and so on.... to filter data from database...these text,text1 are items i am getting from user search form....@selite

Answer (score 0):

Try creating dynamic query here is example query which you can elaborate according to your needs.Here I m assuming that you are fetching data to be searched from user via form.

Now all we have to do is check if user has filled specific field and create query accordingly.In this way your query will not be unnecessarily complex.

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name ";

   if( isset($_REQUEST['location']) && $_REQUEST['location'] != '' ){
        if( strpos($sql, "WHERE") ){
             $sql .= "AND WHERE location like '%$text%'";
        }else{
             $sql .= "WHERE location like '%$text%'";
        };           
   }

   if( isset($_REQUEST['religion']) && $_REQUEST['religion'] != '' ){
       if( strpos($sql, "WHERE") ){
            $sql .= "AND WHERE religion like '%$text%'";
       }else{
            $sql .= "WHERE religion like '%$text%'";
       }
   }

   $result=mysql_query( $sql ) or die("error");
```

Comment: I need to search not same text in all those field ...i have to match text with location ,text1 with gender and so on.... to filter data from database...these text,text1 are items i am getting from user search form. ......For this i have used the code which i have posted but it seems in error @nikhil

Comment: anya the code does exactly same thing which you are asking for, it matches text with location, text1 with religion.MySQL "WHERE" clause will be generated only if user specifies some details."AND" clause makes sure that only results which satisfies all categories will be returned. Still if your requirement is something else trying describing it in detail

Answer (score 0):

Try out full text search like this:-

```
$q="your search value";    
$searchArray = explode(" ", $q);
$query="SELECT * FROM cmusers WHERE  MATCH (`firstname`, `lastname`,`email`) AGAINST ('";
$i=0;
foreach ($searchArray as $word) {
    $query .= "*".$word."* ";
}
$query .= "' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

this will search all key words against all columns
But this need table `myisam` `engine`
By default most tables are with innoDB engine so you can change engine by this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = MYISAM;
```

Comment: It seems valuable to point out that in addition to supporting full text searches,myisam tables are also less durable and not fully transactional... If you're used to innodb, the rules change. Many folks use a separate service for searching, eg elastic search, which typically have improved performance and facilities compared with MySQL full text searches.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this same problem and came up with the following solution.

```
//Building the Query
 if (!empty($_POST['location'])) {
      $location=$_POST['location'];
      $sql[] = "enquiry.location = '%$location%'";
  }
  if (!empty($_POST['religion'])) {
      $religion=$_POST['religion'];
      $sql[] = "enquiry.religion = '%$religion%' ";
  }
  if (!empty($_POST['gender'])) {
      $gender=$_POST['gender'];
      $sql[] = "enquiry.gender LIKE '%$gender%'";
  }
    //etc...
    if (!empty($sql)) {
        $built_query = "SELECT * FROM `enquiry`";
        //This implodes the sql array creating the WHERE statement with appended AND statements
        $built_query .= " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $sql);
    } else {
        $built_query = "SELECT * FROM `enquiry`";   
        }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $built_query);
    $total_records=$result->num_rows;    
    if ($total_records < 1) {
        echo "No records found";
    } else {
        while ($row_result = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
          //Whatever you want to do with the data
        }
```